# Permission denied when i put $

Tags: partitioning

$sudo dd if='/Users/nickzieno/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.img' of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m
dd: /dev/rdiskN: Permission denied

Answer (score 2):

When typing on a command line, a `$` represents the prompt, you should not type this directly in front of sudo, nor anywhere at the beginning of that command.